# How can we iterate Map link linear structure even though they are implemented as red black or AVL tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, hashmap

How can we iterating over the map as if it was a linear data structure and also tell me how we simply put in the key to get the value associated.?

Comment: To confirm - is the question how it's possible to iterate over a container that's backed by a tree structure as though it's a linear structure, or is the question what code you should write to visit the elements of a `std::map`?

Comment: it is to know  how it's possible to iterate over a container that's backed by a tree structure as though it's a linear structure

Comment: Why do you think its as though its a linear structure? Might the iterators for a tree structure not be designed for a tree structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use iterators to iterate over the `map`:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> myMap;
for (auto iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter)
  // do something with iter
```

or you can use the loop syntax:

```cpp
for (auto& myMapPair : myMap)
  // do something with the pair
```

Note that for the first version you can access the key with `iter->first`and the value with `iter->second`as `iter` is an iterator to a pair. For the second version you directly have a reference to a pair so you should use `iter.first` and `iter.second`.

As for finding the value from a key you should do:

```cpp
auto iter = myMap.find(50);
if (iter == myMap.end()) // didn't find anything
  // do something
else // you found something
  // do something
```

Comment: I know these basics but like given that a MAP is internally implemented as BST, how are we iterating in this manner.  
tree is never iterated in this manner 
we either do level order or recursive calls...  Then how is it possible for the map

Comment: An iterator is an object that provides an abstraction on how to go through another object. Although I'm not familiar with the particular implementation of the iterator of a `map` I suppose that internally the iterator implements a kind of search in the tree. If you really want to know how it is implemented you can check the stdlib code yourself :)

Comment: Also, here calling `iter++` is in fact a call to the member function `operator++` from the `map<T>::iterator`, it is not a pointer increment nor a integer increment like you would do in an array.

Comment: okay now i understand that the iterator function might be overloaded in a particular manner such that we feel that iteration is made in linear order but actually the tree is being iterated over.
Thanks